# Problem with "Span.as_doc()" method in Spacy

Tags: spacy

I am working on extraction of dative and direct object using Spacy. Noun.chunks already have already dependency tagging for their roots like `dative` and `dobj`, and what I am trying to do is to get `Span` and save it as Doc to apply further analysis.

I have the following code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
doc = nlp(open("/-textfile").read())
```

so far so good, next I got Span objects;

```
datives = []

for dat in doc.noun_chunks:
    if dat.root.dep_ == "dative" and dat.root.head.pos_ == "VERB":
            dative.append(dat.sent)
```

Now I have all the sentences with `noun.chunks` of which roots are dative and head is a `VERB`

However, I would to like get `token` data like from the `datives []`

```
dativesent = datives.as_doc()
```

But the problem is as `datives []` is already a list, I cannot convert it to a `DOC`.

How can I save the sentences with dative-noun.chunks as a `DOC?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a sentence (which is a `Span`) just like a `Doc` to access the tokens:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("She gave the dog a bone. He read a book. They gave her a book.")

dative_sents = []
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    if nc.root.dep_ == "dative" and nc.root.head.pos_ == "VERB":
        dative_sents.append(nc.sent)

for dative_sent in dative_sents:
    print("Sentence with dative:", dative_sent.text)
    for token in dative_sent:
        print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Sentence with dative: She gave the dog a bone.
She PRON nsubj
gave VERB ROOT
the DET det
dog NOUN dative
a DET det
bone NOUN dobj
. PUNCT punct

Sentence with dative: They gave her a book.
They PRON nsubj
gave VERB ROOT
her PRON dative
a DET det
book NOUN dobj
. PUNCT punct
```

Comment: Awesome. I have been having nightmares for 3 days. So, no really need to use span.as_doc().